# How I can exit from next line code in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function:

```
onTap: () {
                              FunctionsClass.checkToken(context);
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => AttackDetailScreen(
                                          idAttack:
                                              data[index]['id'].toString())));
                            },
```

Checktoken function:

```
static Future<http.Response> checkToken(BuildContext context) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var url = kUrlAPI + 'checkToken/';

    var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + prefs.getString('token'),
        });

    var convertDataToJson = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if(convertDataToJson['code'] == 401){
      Loader.hide();
      showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomDialog(
          pressedAction: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          type: 'w',
          title: kWarningTitle,
          description: kGenericError,
          buttonText: kCloseText,
        ),
      );
//exit for next function
    }
  }
```

I want if **convertDataToJson['code'] == 401**, show dialog and not execute Navigator.
Something to not execute the next method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a value from your `checkToken` function that indicates whether the navigator should push or not. For example you can return `null` in case of an error or simply return `boolean` where `true` means push or `false` means don't push *(or you could return the error string and check it inside `onTap` if you prefer that)*.

Let's assume you choose to return `null` if the navigator shouldn't push the page, then you can do this:

```dart
onTap: () {
 FunctionsClass.checkToken(context).then((value) {
  if(value == null) { 
   return; // don't do anything
  } else {
     Navigator.push(
         context,
         MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => AttackDetailScreen(idAttack: data[index]['id'].toString())));
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: How I can change the return value in boolean in **checkToken** with <http.Response>

Comment: @joisberg In your code, you don't seem to return anything from checkToken so you can replace <http.Response> with <bool> and then inside the function just return `true` or `false` after you verify the token (i.e., under `if(convertDataToJson['code'] == 401`). Another option, create an intermidate function that takes the `<http.Response>`, examine it then return `true` or `false` based on the examination of the response. You may wanna move the `showDialog` code to the `onTap` and then show the dialog when `false` is return (where I commented `don't do anything`)

Answer (score 0):

Try using try/catch for unexpected error too. And 'throw' a custom error.
This is consider a good practice.

```dart
static Future<http.Response> checkToken(BuildContext context) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var url = kUrlAPI + 'checkToken/';
    try {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + prefs.getString('token'),
        });

    var convertDataToJson = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if(convertDataToJson['code'] == 401){
      
    //exit for next function
    throw Exception('some error');
    }
} catch (error) {
 throw error;
}
  }
```

And use ".then" and '.catchError' while calling a Future function.

```
onTap: () {
    FunctionsClass.checkToken(context).then((_) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => AttackDetailScreen(
            idAttack:
            data[index]['id'].toString(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).catchError((onEroor){
      Loader.hide();
      showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomDialog(
          pressedAction: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          type: 'w',
          title: kWarningTitle,
          description: kGenericError,
          buttonText: kCloseText,
        ),
      );
    };
  },
```